# SQLite Database becomes read only

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a c# plug-in that writes data to an SQLite database on our networked directory.  We implement a Panzura Server at our office (That I don't know much about). https://panzura.com/solutions-now/aec-solution/

Two weeks in a row, at about 12:30pm - this Sqlite database became read only. On the first occasion, the "read-only" status was was released over the weekend.  Unfortunately, that did not happen this weekend.

when I step through the code, i get an `SQLiteException 'attempt to write to a readonly database'.` error.

If i use `FileInfo` on the db file, the `'readonly'` attribute is false.

most of the sql statements are as following...

```
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " +
                            "`User`(`UserName`, `UserLevel`) " +
                            "VALUES('" + System.Environment.UserName + "', '0')";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
```

My first observation is that the opening and closing of the connection may be redundant with the using statement.

I also noticed this sql statement...

```
            conn.Open();

            string sel = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE `userName`='"+System.Environment.UserName+"' LIMIT 1";

            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sel, conn))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        NumOfResults++;

                        if (rdr.GetString(2) == "1")
                        {
                            count = 1;
                        } else { count = 0;  }
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this case, the connection is opened, a using statement is used, but the connection is not closed.  I wonder (even though this routing runs a number of times a week) if this is leaving the database in a read only state? Although, i thought leaving a connection open would return a `SQLITE BUSY` exception.

At this point, I don't know if this read-only issue is being caused by my code or the server.  I've been running this plugin for months with out issue - although the number of users accessing it is increasing.

I'm not really sure how to trouble shoot this because once the SQLIte database is in a read only state, it's not really usable.  How do i force it out of a read only state?

I'm not even really sure what the read-only state means right now - is the file read-only? or does the database have connections open that need to be closed?

another detail; could the compress attribute on the connection string be an issue?

```
@"Data Source=I:\Practice Standards\BCMS\families.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True; ";
```

Comment: First of all, the connection `conn.Open()` and `conn.Close()` statements are *not* redundant since the using statement is for the `SQLiteCommand cmd` object.  But you should wrap the entire connection use in a `try...catch...finally` block and put the `conn.Close()` inside the finally block.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely close the connection at the end of the second code snippet, but once again it should be wrapped in a `try..finally` block to avoid loose connections due to an error.

Comment: I appreciate this and will wrap these in try catches.  Note the lack of the conn.close();  Could that render the database "read only"?  That would be odd to me as this select statement is called 50 times a day - at least.

Comment: As for the Panzura server, if you suspect that it could be the issue, you need to go to IT and/or Panzura for solutions, especially if you don't know anything about it then go to proper source(s).

Comment: As for the lack of `conn.close()`... it depends on a few things.  A well-designed connection object should close the connection when it goes out of scope (when the object is disposed), but sqlite from c# is an interop call (managed .Net to C code) and the object might not closed and be garbage collected properly if the connection is not explicitly closed.  I'm not an expert on that, but it's worth just being consistent and closing all connections the same way.  Also, if you have any code with exceptions that are ignored (thrown and not properly handled), they could likewise leave db locked.

Comment: Perhaps read/review [appropriate uses for sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).  It sounds like you need a true client-server database:  1) Is it only the plugin that opens the database, or multiple clients accessing a database file directly?  2) If it's a Panzura cloud solution and the problems started in conjunction with the new server, that's going to stretch file-based access even further... even if you do find a solution to the current read-only/locking.

Comment: well, it's likely this is the wrong db for the application as it is on a network server.  I really don't expect more than a couple hundred calls to it a day - so figured it was simple and would work.  Im rewriting for sql on azure and will take a bit of effort and time.  In the meantime - is there a way to help band-aid the situation?  can I manually close all the connections to a sqlite database perhaps through DB Browser for SQLite?

Comment: sqlite is an in-process database engine.  DB Browser implements the same engine (possibly different versions) that your application uses.  There is no dedicated server the manages connections, rather each connection must cooperate with all other connections, so DB Browser has nothing special that can terminate other connections.  Sqlite uses the operating and/or file system capabilities to implement transaction and integrity features of the database, so the read-only state is likely due to un-closed connections that leave file locks unresolved, etc.

Comment: The band-aids would be to do what I already suggested.  Investigate capabilities of the network server, whether it has admin features that let you see and manage file locks.  Is there any sort of backup or sync process occurring at the time you notice problems?  Next, change the code to implement better database connection pattern like I said, using `try...finally` blocks to ensure `conn.close()` is called.  Log all connection activity and/or catch exceptions rather than ignoring them.  If you have many clients, ensure that none of your apps are crashing, thereby leaving connections open, etc.